# How can I efficiently deploy Entity Framework Core changes to existing database with data residing in individual users' computer?

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

> **Note:**
> After further searching, I found this article, which seems to have all
> possible solutions.
> https://blog.infernored.com/the-correct-way-to-run-ef-database-migrations/
>
> I also found this **YouTube** Video on how to create Bundle
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBxSONeKbPk is super helpful.

I have plan to use Entity Framework Core for Desktop application.
Releasing the initial EF related work seems starlight forward, as new database is getting created.

But once application is established on users' desktop, I cannot overwrite the database, as user will have their data.

There will be periodic update/changes (Data, Class/Table Structure etc.) to application. How can I efficiently deploy Entity Framework changes to existing database with data residing in individual users' computer?

If this was Web app using DevOps, I would have created pipeline to handle changes, upon PR gets applied.

But for desktop app, I will have to deal with existing database with existing data. And I need to deploy changes, as periodic patch/bugfix etc.

Comment: What is the question? You have found migrations - use them. They are designed to apply changes to existing databases.